# How to set the time zone of datetime values in RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone, rails-admin

In [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin), when editing a record, datetime values are always displayed in UTC.

When I set the value it is recognized in my current timezone setting (PST). Here's an image of the value that I set it to within the edit view before saving:

[image: Setting value to 8pm]

After saving, the value is displayed in UTC:

[image: Value displayed as 12pm]

**Is there any way to display these values in a specific timezone, so that administration of datetime attributes in RailsAdmin is less confusing for the user?**

Comment: I am not familiar with activeAdmin codebase, but you might be interested in this blog post i wrote about rails and timezones - http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/ - i would think set up your app in UTC and then override each request with the appropriate user timezone, rails should do the right thing, unless activeAdmin is doing something odd.

Comment: Thanks house9, I'll check that out. Just to clarify its RailsAdmin, not ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following gist, in addition to setting a default timezone, resolved my issue. PST Datetimes are now displayed in RailsAdmin views. I had to precompile assets to get it working on my heroku environments:

```
# rails_admin.rb
# https://gist.github.com/jackdesert/7090731

require 'rails_admin/config/fields/base'

module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Fields
      module Types
        class Datetime < RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Base
          def value
            value_in_default_time_zone = bindings[:object].send(name)
            return nil if value_in_default_time_zone.nil?
            pacific_time_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
            value_in_default_time_zone.in_time_zone(pacific_time_zone)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In `staging.rb` and `production.rb` I specified the PST timezone:

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having updated models save there time values to local time and instead only show in local time and save in UTC?